# No Data in Tmp File Created

Tags: scala, java-io

I have the following scalatest where I need to create a temporary file and add some content, call the main method and then see if the correct output is produced.

I can see the file created in "/tmp" but it is always empty. It's like the BufferedWriter is not writing to it. What am I doing wrong?

```
  "provided with a non empty file" should {
    import java.io.{BufferedWriter, File, FileWriter}
    val log: File = File.createTempFile("data", ".log")
    log.renameTo(new File(log.getAbsolutePath + "data.log"))
    val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log))
    bw.write("This is the temporary file content")
    bw.close()
    log.deleteOnExit()
    "print info" in {
      val stream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream()
      Console.withOut(stream) {
        val args = Array(log.getAbsolutePath)
        main(args)
      }
      assert(stream.toString.trim == "This is the temporary file content")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to call `bw.flush` after `bw.write`?

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you think my test is completing before the file is written to?

Comment: Yes I think the test is completing before it has flushed to file because I added a before and after to the test suite and put the writing to the file in the before and the test works now